# What is the fastest way to relocate lots of items in the tree?

Tags: content-management

We have a Sitecore site that currently exists in production with a lot of content, on the order of half a million article items and supporting content around those articles. We have to relocate those items to another area in the tree (for business reasons that aren't relevant to the question). The structure of the items will remain the same, we just need to move them to a different area.  The `<site>` node start paths will be updated to reflect the new path, so no urls will change.

I have to get this done as quickly as possible to minimize content authoring downtime. We also need to publish this change, and a full publish takes hours. What's the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you just use `Move to` from **Home** tab? I am not sure if I see a challenge here. Are you talking about multiple nodes under node **A**, that need to be moved except the node **A**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the root item.

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Result

[image]

**EDIT: Included to add this**

And yes, as you point out in comments. Instead of publishing this change, execute this operation in both "master" and "web" (and as needed, if you have more databases in play)

Comment: Btw, to make sure this worked as intended; I sneakily created the "New Folder" in between Step 1 and Step 2 screenshots. No "sleight of hand" intended ;-)

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question I need to publish these changes, and a publish takes approximately forever.  I'll edit the question.  But you're saying create new folders, publish them, then execute the move manually on master and web.  Simple!  Thanks!  I just tried that on my local and it only took a couple minutes to execute the move.  I was expecting it to take as long as a publish.

Comment: No, since the move should - at least theoretically - only update 1 item, and then the Descendants table (if active). It's about as fast as it gets I think.

Answer (score 3):

Another super fast way to do this is using Sitecore Powershell Extensions found here in the Sitecore Marketplace (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx). SPE is now one of the most popular modules for Sitecore. In one line of code you can move one or thousands of items very quickly as in this example below:

```
Move-Item -Path "master:\content\home\sample item\Sample Item 1" -Destination "master:\content\home\sample
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to move large amount of items would be to used /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx tool which comes default with Sitecore.

One thing to keep in mind is that, this tool will skip lot of pipeline processors normally executing while doing the same operation using Content Editor.

So, you need to find a way to adjust the links in these items, in case you are not moving full root node of the site. (for that, you can write a custom tool to update links as you needed if you have a common pattern)